# Script not firing on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a Javascript run when a checkbox is selected/deselected that calls a php file and passes the value of the checkbox that was selected. The script is firing but the value is not being passed as a parameter and I can't work out why I'm doing wrong here.

Here's an example the table cell that contains the checkbox with the script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td.article-export").click(function() {
    var selectedRatingsIDs = $(this).val();
    var checkedState = $(this).is(":checked");
    console.log(selectedRatingsIDs);
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('updateExportSelections.php', {
      type: 'updateSelections',
      selectedRatingsIDs: selectedRatingsIDs,
      selectionType: checkedState
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      //console.log( data );
      if (data.error) {
        var ajaxError = (data.text);
        var errorAlert = 'There was an error updating the  Selections - ' + ajaxError + '. Please contact the help desk';
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {}

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an error updating the Selections - AJAX request error. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + '. Please contact the help desk';
      $this.attr('checked', false); // Unchecks it
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td id="RT12784" class="article-select form-check">
  <label>
    <input name="article-export" type="checkbox" value="RT12784">
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
  </label>
</td>
```

The selectedRatingsIDs variable is not getting populated - in this example it should be passing RT12784 to the script.

Comment: So script is firing, but `$(this).val()` is `undefined`?

Comment: $(this) on the "$(this).is(":checked"); " is reference to the "TD". To get the check box value, us an id or an exact reference to the checkbox.

Comment: @RobinThomas script fires but the selectedRatingsIDs variable is empty.

Comment: What is the value of `$(this)`?

Comment: @RobinThomas <td value="RT12784" class="article-select form-check"><label><input name="article-export" type="checkbox" value="RT12784"><span>&nbsp;</span></label></td>

Comment: @RobinThomas $(this) refers to the previous jquery selector which is td.article-export BUT the checkbox is nested (inside the td) so with your solution you will not access the checkbox element thus the checked value.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator The issue is about `selectedRatingsIDs` variables being not populated. I wrote the solution to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$(this)` within your event handler refers to the DOMNode `<td value="RT12784" class="article-select form-check">`, you cannot use `$(this).val()`

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. When called on an empty collection, it returns undefined.
>
> https://api.jquery.com/val/

Since in your case, its a `<td>` node, `.val()` will not work, and will return `undefined`.

---

Instead you can use: `$(this).attr('value')`.

Comment: The problem is that the checkbox is nested on the td, so that solution will not function smoothly,

Answer (score 0):

A few corrections, it does not make sense to not have a table element outside td and $(this) refers to $("td.article-export").
Clean up a little bit your code and **pay attention to nested check event**. the rest of the code looks ok.

**HTML:**

```
<table border='1' id="myTable">
<td id="RT12784" class="article-select form-check">
  <label>
    <input name="article-export" type="checkbox" value="RT12784">
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
  </label>
</td>
</table>
```

**JQuery:**

```
var chkobj = $('[name="article-export"]')
var tableobj=$("#myTable")

$(document).ready(function() {
tableobj.on("click", "td", function() {

var selectedRatingsIDs = $(this).attr('id');
var isChecked = chkobj.is(':checked');
 
console.log(isChecked);
console.log(selectedRatingsIDs)

   });
});
```

I created a fiddle for you go to jsfiddle.net and append /#&togetherjs=9DxOs9F5ps to the URL